# AppCompatDialogFragment with ConstraintLayout dialog width

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, appcompatdialogfragment

I'm trying to have a AppCompatDialogFragment with a root layout as a ConstraintLayout.

The root layout have a layout_width set to wrap_content.
But when I execute the code, the dialog is shrink have a fixed width even if the content change.

Here's the layout code generated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                             android:orientation="vertical"
  >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tempus tristique ornare. Aenean ut magna in diam aliquet accumsan. "
    android:textSize="36sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's how i inflate the layout:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_dialog, container, false);
```

[image: Long text]

[image: Short text]

We can see that with a long text the dialog hit some sort of "max width" (even without the attribute).

How can i have a dialog that wrap its content in width without this "limit" ?

Comment: 1) Do you inflate the layout in `onCreateView()` ? 2) Please share values/style.xml

Comment: Hi, yes the layout is inflated in `onCreateView()`. Also i have tested my code snippet on a blank project, and the behavior is the same... i don't think it is related to styles...

Comment: That's ok, I only wanted to know if you have done anything to style the Dialog(Fragment). Really interesting question.

Answer (score 3):

There is a pair of `Window` style attributes named `android:windowMinWidthMajor` and `android:windowMinWidthMinor`.

> The minimum width the window is allowed to be, along the major [minor] axis of the screen

(quoted from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Window_windowMinWidthMajor))

If you use a `Theme` for your `Dialog` by defining some style

```
<style name="FragmentDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="windowMinWidthMajor">@dimen/dialog_fragment_width</item>
    <item name="windowMinWidthMinor">@dimen/dialog_fragment_width</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@dimen/dialog_fragment_width</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@dimen/dialog_fragment_width</item>
</style>
```

and setting

```
<item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/FragmentDialogStyle</item>
<item name="dialogTheme">@style/FragmentDialogStyle</item>
```

in the application `Theme`, then the `Dialog` width will be precisely `dialog_fragment_width` *if* you also use

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

with your `TextView`.

Whereas if you keep using

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

the "max width" you observed will restrain your `Dialog` width.

By the way, if you color the backgrounds of the `TextView` and the `ConstraintLayout`, you will observe that only when using the `0dp` width value all the margins are correct.

So it seems that your best option is to set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for the `TextView` and to provide different values for `dialog_fragment_width`, depending on the current screen (for Nougat+: app window) width. For this, you'll need different directories like `res/values-w600dp`.

Please note: I tested with emulators for a tablet running Marshmallow and a phone running Lollipop. Although it worked, I'd be happier if I also could explain why. So I think this is more like half an answer but I wanted to share my observations.

Comment: Yes, this is what i ended up doing. I was probably wrong pointing the Constraint Layout, I had the same behavior with a RelativeLayout.